# Unable to find file or directory Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to call a Python module but get the following error "test.sh not found"

but this file is found in the directory.

```
process = subprocess.Popen("test.sh",shell=True)
```

The script and the sh file are located in the same directory.

Comment: Try `sh test.sh` or `bash test.sh` or even `xterm test.sh`.

Comment: do you also call the python script from the same directory?

Comment: @Torxed..thanks..it worked

Answer (score 3):

By default the current directory is not in PATH therefore just `"test.sh"` is not found, the minimal change is to use `"./tests.sh"`.

To run a shell script, make sure you have a valid shebang e.g., `#!/bin/sh` and the file has executable permissions (`chmod u+x test.sh`).

If you are running Python script from a different directory then you also need to provide the  full path:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from subprocess import check_call

script_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
check_call(os.path.join(script_dir, "test.sh"))
```

Note: there is no `shell=True` that starts the additional unnecessary shell process here. `realpath` resolve symlinks, you could use `abspath` instead if you want the path relative script's symlink instead of the script file itself.